# laravel: how to check item availability in each category?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, nested-sets

I use [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) and I can get all categories and its children with this code:

code1:

```
$categories = $this->traverse(Category::defaultOrder()->get()->toTree(), null);
```

For checking product availability in each category,
  I use this code:

code2:

```
if($category ->products()->exists()) {...}
```

Can I combine these two codes?

I want The code 1, returns only the categories containing the products.

Currently, I use this code:

code 3:

```
  $temp = [];
  $categories = $this->traverse(Category::defaultOrder()->get()->toTree(), null);
  foreach($categories as $key=>$value){

      $category = Category::find($key);
      if($category ->products()->exists()){
         $temp[$key] = $value;
      }
  }
  $categories = $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check existence of relationship in a DB query:

```
Category::has('products')->defaultOrder()->get()
```